# Why don't dentists use stitches after doing a tooth extraction?

Tags: dentistry, surgery, coagulation

I had tooth extraction in 2007. Dentist didn't use stitches just gave me a cotton told me to hold onto it with teeth. Bleeding last for 3-4 hours.

> Usually, however, bleeding will **almost completely stop within eight
>   hours** of the surgery, ....

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dental_extraction#Post-extraction_healing)

Why do dental doctors allow patients to bleed if there is a alternative to it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not a black-and-white rule that no sutures are used in dental surgery. There are disadvantages to suturing, e. g.:

> Clinical disadvantages of suturing: Although suturing postsurgically
>   has many benefits, there are some disadvantages. Suture material that
>   is braided can often act like a plaque trap and soak up bacteria. This
>   is known as the "wick effect." (3) Bacteria in close adherence to the
>   wound site can cause infection and delayed healing. In addition,
>   breakdown products from the absorbable suture material itself have
>   been shown to cause an inflammatory reaction in the tissue in certain
>   cases. (4) The length of surgery may also be increased, since
>   suturing—especially in advanced cases—can be time-consuming and
>   technical. Studies have shown that any increase in surgical time can
>   also be correlated with an increase in the postoperative pain a
>   patient may experience. (5)

Source: https://www.perioimplantadvisory.com/clinical-tips/article/16412251/alternative-to-suturing-reduces-surgical-time-for-dental-procedures

1. Silverstein LH. Essential principles of dental suturing for the implant surgeon. Dent Implantol Update. 2005;16(1):1-7.
2. Cohen ES. Sutures and suturing. In: Atlas of Cosmetic Reconstructive Periodontal Surgery. 2nd ed. Philadelphia, PA: Lea & Febiger; 1994:9-30.
3. Manor A, Kaffe I. Unusual foreign body reaction to a braided silk suture: a case report. J Periodontol. 1982;53(2):86-88. doi: 10.1902/jop.1982.53.2.86.
4. Lilly GE, Salem JE, Armstrong JH, Cutcher JL. Reaction of oral tissues to suture materials. Oral Surg Oral Med Oral Pathol. 1969;28(3):432-438.
5. Ip HY, Abrishami A, Peng PW, Wong J, Chung F. Predictors of postoperative pain and analgesic consumption: a qualitative systematic review. Anesthesiology. 2009;111(3):657-677. doi: 10.1097/ALN.0b013e3181aae87a.